Are there problems with the 2nd question’s image?
A few weeks ago I posted the following question:
A simple cross-number puzzle
This question had a 3x3 grid which I represented by an image I uploaded.
Today I posted a similar question:
A simple cross-number puzzle # 2
The 2nd question is different but uses the same grid as the 1st question.  So instead of uploading the same grid a second time, in the 2nd question I simply used the web address from the 1st question. I did this to save storage space.
Are there any negative issues to not uploading the grid a second time for the 2nd question?

Heptagon image embedding test: https://i.sstatic.net/Oq8Chs18.png

Septagon test.

This is perfectly fine. Images may be used in a post other than when they were initially uploaded. For example, a common workaround to link an image within a comment is to upload the image via the post editor, then copy the link to the comment.
